# Using one button to display different images on an oled display

Tags: arduino, oledb, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am using an oled display with the `Adafruit_GFX` and `Adafruit_SSD1306` libraries.

I am trying to create a menu on my oled display (a series of different images). I have created code that, when one button is pressed, the screen changes to one image, and when pressed again, the screen changes to the second image. However, I would like to add a third image to this, so that, when you push the button, the first image is displayed, then, you press the button again, the second image is displayed, then you press the button again and the third image is displayed. How would I go about this, I have tried for hours with no success.

This is my code, I did not include the codes for my images as it is too large.

```cpp
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
#include <splash.h>

#define bitmap_height   128
#define bitmap_width    64

#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>

#define YELLOW 0xFFE0
#define OLED_RESET -1

Adafruit_SSD1306 display(OLED_RESET);

int buttonState1 = 0;
const int BUTTON_PIN1 = 2;
int toggle = 0;

const unsigned char s1 [] PROGMEM = {
    //image code
};

const unsigned char s2 [] PROGMEM = {
    //second image code
};

void setup() {
    pinMode(BUTTON_PIN1, INPUT_PULLUP);
    display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C);
    display.clearDisplay(); 
}
 
void loop() 
{
    buttonState1 = digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN1);
    
    if (buttonState1 == LOW) {
        if (toggle ==0) {
            display.clearDisplay();
            display.drawBitmap(0, 0, s1, bitmap_height, bitmap_width, WHITE);
            display.display();
            toggle = 1;
        } else {
            display.clearDisplay();
            display.drawBitmap(0, 0, s2, bitmap_height, bitmap_width, WHITE);
            display.display();
            toggle = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is my code:

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (untested):

```cpp
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
#include <splash.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>

#define bitmap_height   128
#define bitmap_width    64

#define YELLOW 0xFFE0
#define OLED_RESET -1

Adafruit_SSD1306 display(OLED_RESET);
int buttonState1 = HIGH;
int lastState    = HIGH;
int currentImage = 0;
const int BUTTON_PIN1 = 2;

const unsigned char s1 [] PROGMEM = {
    //image code
};
const unsigned char s2 [] PROGMEM = {
    //second image code
};
const unsigned char s3 [] PROGMEM = {
    //third image code
};

const unsigned char *images[] = {s1, s2, s3};

void setup()
{
    pinMode(BUTTON_PIN1, INPUT_PULLUP);
    display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C);
    display.clearDisplay();
}

void loop()
{
    buttonState1 = digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN1);

    // you may want to add some button debounce code here

    if ((buttonState1 == LOW) && (buttonState1 != lastState)) {

        if (++currentImage > 2) {
            currentImage = 0;
        }

        display.clearDisplay(); // Not sure if you need this (could cause flicker)
        display.drawBitmap(0, 0, images[currentImage], bitmap_height, bitmap_width, WHITE);
        display.display();

        lastState = buttonState1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and unfortunately did not work. Thanks so much for the help though I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to put the `screed data` in an array. Then you could access each screen using its index.

like this

```cpp
#define MAX_SCREENS 3

const unsigned char s1[] = { /* image 1 data*/ };
const unsigned char s2[] = { /* image 2 data*/ };
const unsigned char s3[] = { /* image 3 data*/ };

const unsigned char *screen[MAX_SCREEN] =
{
    s1,
    s2,
    s3
};
```

And you need to use state change detection to detect when button is pressed and then increase the `currentScreen` variable if it is smaller than `MAX_SCREEN` else set it to `0`.

Use this for reference

```cpp
void loop ()
{
    bool state = digitalRead(buttonPIN);
    static bool previousState = false;
    static int currentScreen = 0;
    
    if(state != previousState && state) {
        
        if(currentScreen == MAX_SCREENS)
            currentScreen = 0;
        else
            currentScreen++;
            
        // code for displaying the screen
      
    }

    previousState = state;

}
```

And then you can display the the image (screen) using `screen[currentScreen]`.

**If you don't know how state change detection works, you can find it in examples in Arduino ide**

Comment: I have changed my code, I'm not sure how to upload it to here. By using your code i keep receiving the error "exit status 1
declaration of 'screen' as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first".    Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: My bad, The array declaration should be `const unsigned char *screen[MAX_SCREENS]`. I will change it in the answer.